# How receive/posta data using URLs in django?

Tags: python, django, post, get, django-rest-framework

I am new in django. I need to write a application that read, write data using service links.

For example, I have a URLs like:

http://site.com/something/LoadProducts/

http://site.com/something/DeleteProductById/ and so on.

Can anyone give me any example to work with GET, POST urls for CRUD operations. Thanks

Comment: Your question is very basic and extremely broad. Have you read the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/)? It has [a separate chapter on connecting views to URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/). URL dispatcher is also [extremely well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/). Please, start by completing the tutorial (don't worry it's pretty short) and come back to ask if something still isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks, but I have read turorials from 01 to 05. there is not any explain there about it

Comment: Ok, try to clarify your question then. It's not entirely clear what do you want to know. Maybe try illustrating your question with a detailed example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
# form imports here
# model imports here

# get all objects
def get_view(request):
    objects = YourModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'all-objects.html', {'objects': objects}

# make a new object
def make_new_obj(request):
    form = YourForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'make-new-obj.html', {'form': form}

# get an object by id
def get_single_object_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(YourModel, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'obj-detail.html', {'obj': obj}

# update an object
def update_obj(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(YourModel, pk=id)
    form = YourForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'update-obj.html',
        {'obj': obj, 'form': form}

# delete an object
def delete_obj(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(YourModel, pk=id)
    obj.delete()
    # do something else like redirect to the object index, etc
    # you'll probably want to make this a two-step process
```

Obviously, there is a lot of code here that can be combined, so mix and match as needed. All of this code is very well covered in the Django documentation...

Model Instance Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/

Working with forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/